# C# Regex for invalid characters

Tags: c#, regex, validation

Hi I have a requirement to validate an input that should accept only alphanumeric, -, _ 
To test this i am using the following code

```
 string pattern = @"[^a-z A-Z 0-9._-]$";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(m_ModelName.Value, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return (matches.Count > 0);
```

if the count is >0 it means there are invalid characters. But it never returns according to my expectations. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. This is strictly c#

Comment: Try escaping the period in the regex, using a backslash `\.`, otherwise it's probably matching all characters - `@"[^a-z A-Z 0-9\._-]$"`

Comment: @Mark The period in a character class [loses its regex meaning](http://regex101.com/r/eF8oB0).

Comment: @HamZa Thanks! At least I learned something! :-)

Comment: @user841612 you probably need to remove `$` since it means `end of string`.

Comment: try using `IsMatch` this will state true or false

Comment: On a side note, you don't need to include a-z and A-Z, since you're setting the IgnoreCase option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string pattern = @"[^a-z A-Z 0-9._-]$";
```

This regex just matches the last character in the string (because of the $ anchor).

You probably want something like:

```
 string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$";
 return Regex.IsMatch(m_ModelName.Value, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Also you may look at the `\w` character class.